# Выделение памяти на структуру

Tags: c, указатели

Всем привет! Есть функции:

```
unsigned long GenerateRandomBlock(RANDOM_BLOCK **ppRandomBlock)
unsigned long FreeRandomBlock(RANDOM_BLOCK *pRandomBlock)
```

Где `RANDOM_BLOCK` структура вида:

```
{
    unsigned char *pRandomData;
    unsigned long ulRandomLen;
}
```

**1-я функция должна:**

1) Выделить память на структуру `RANDOM_BLOCK`

2) Сгенерировать случайное `ulRandomLen` в пределах [0;128]

3) Выделить память на массив `pRandomData` длиной `ulRandomLen`

4) Заполнить массив `pRandomData` случайными данными.

5) Вернуть ноль если операция выполнена успешно.

**2-я функция должна:**

1) освобождать всю память, связанную с `pRandomBlock`

2) Вернуть ноль если операция выполнена успешно.

**Сделал так:**

```
unsigned long GenerateRandomBlock(RANDOM_BLOCK **pRandomBlock)
{
    *pRandomBlock = (RANDOM_BLOCK *) malloc(sizeof(RANDOM_BLOCK));

    if (*pRandomBlock != NULL)
    {
        pRandomBlock->ulRandomLen = GenerateRandomNumber(0, 128);
        pRandomBlock->pRandomData = (unsigned char *) malloc(pRandomBlock->ulRandomLen * sizeof(pRandomBlock->ulRandomLen));
    }
    return 0;
}

unsigned long FreeRandomBlock(RANDOM_BLOCK *pRandomBlock)
{
    free(pRandomBlock->pRandomData);
    free(pRandomBlock);

    if (pRandomBlock->pRandomData == NULL && pRandomBlock == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

unsigned int GenerateRandomNumber(int m, int n)
{
    if (n != 0)
    {
        return rand() % n + m;
    }

    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Со второй функцией проблем нет. А вот в первой не могу обратиться к полям структуры.

**Вот что говорит компилятор:**

> *left of '->ulRandomLen' must point to class/struct/union/generic type RandomBlock*
>
> *expression must have pointer-to-class type*

Я так понял что массив `RANDOM_BLOCK` уже есть. Нам передается указатель на этот массив и нам нужно выделить память на ЭЛЕМЕНТ массива `RANDOM_BLOCK`.

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не сообщили, что должна вернуть первая функция в случае, если выделение памяти было неуспешным. Ваша реализация функции во всех случаях возвращает 0. как будто бы она успешно отработала.

Так же совершенно непонятно, почему она имеет тип возвращаемого значения `unsigned long`. В C является общепринятым подходом, что функции, которые с помощью возвращаемого значения сигнализируют об успешности или неуспешности операции, имеют тип возвращаемого значения `int` или `_Bool`.

Оба этих предложения

```
    pRandomBlock->ulRandomLen = GenerateRandomNumber(0, 128);
    pRandomBlock->pRandomData = (unsigned char *) malloc(pRandomBlock->ulRandomLen * sizeof(pRandomBlock->ulRandomLen));
```

из первой функции неверны. Более того совершенно непонятно, почему выделяется память для объектов размером `sizeof(pRandomBlock->ulRandomLen)` Как я понимаю, вы должны выделить символьный массив.
Правильно было бы записать

```
( *pRandomBlock )->ulRandomLen = GenerateRandomNumber(0, 128);
( *pRandomBlock )->pRandomData = (unsigned char *) malloc(pRandomBlock->ulRandomLen * sizeof( unsigned char ));
```

Кроме того ваша функция не заполняет выделенный массив случайными данными.

Что касается второй функции, то возвращать из нее какое-то значение бессмысленно, так как стандартная функция `free` также не возвращает какое-либо значение. Она имеет тип возвращаемого значения `void`. Поэтому и эту функцию можно было бы определеить с типом возвращаемого значения `void`.
Кроме того функция `free` не обнуляет указатели. Ей указатели передаются по значенипю. Поэтому данная проверка

```
if (pRandomBlock->pRandomData == NULL && pRandomBlock == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}

else
{
    return -1;
}
```

просто бессмысленна.

Функция генерации случайного числа в заданном диапазоне также неверна. Например, рассмотрите диапазон `[10, 15]`. В соответствии с тем, как сейчас написана ваша функция, она будет возвращать значения в диапазоне `[10, 24]`, так как `rand() % 15` возвращает числа в диапазоне `[0, 14]`, и если прибавить 10, то получится диапазон `[10, 24]`.

Более того, я думаю, вы должны проверять правильность задания граничных значений диапазон в функции, то есть проверять, что `m` всегда меньше `n`.
И, кстати сказать, почему это `n` не может быть равным 0? Пользователь вашей функции, например, может захотеть иметь диапазон случайных числе `[-10, 0]`.

Я бы определил эту функцию следующим образом

```
int GenerateRandomNumber( int m, int n )
{
    if ( !( m < n ) ) return RAND_MAX;

    return rand() % ( n - m + 1 ) + m; 
}
```

Comment: эта проверка `pRandomBlock->pRandomData == NULL && pRandomBlock == NULL` на самом деле вредная. Она может стать причиной падения.

Comment: @KoVadim Как я написал, она бессмысленная, так как указатели не обнуляются после вызова free.

Comment: Вы читаете, что я пишу или нет?

Comment: @Djasir, поскольку `sizeof(char)` **всегда == 1** (а вот CHAR_BIT не обязательно 8, хотя в большинстве архитектур это так), то умножать не нужно. (впрочем, хороший компилятор при соответствующем уровне оптимизации сам это уберет)

Comment: Коллеги, обычно такие проверки пишут в стиле `pRandomBlock && pRandomBlock->pRandomData == ...`

Comment: @KoVadim  Ваш комментарий как и данная проверка в контексте приведенного кода бессмысленны. Сама проверка ни к какому падению привести не может. К падению могут привести действия с указателями помимо проверки.:)

Comment: Представьте, что в функцию передали null. Правда оно упадет раньше, ещё в процессе free. Но..

Comment: @KoVadim  В какую функцию? Если я проверяю, что указатель равен NULL, то с чего это, вдруг, я должен передавать его в функцию, которая требует не NULL указатель?! Зачем тогда проверка? И опять-таки, как она может привести к падению функции?!

Comment: Ну ребятки, от души спасибо что открыли глаза студенту! Сам я программирую на Java. Но вот пришлось и с С/C++ столкнуться. Кернигана читал а вот Страуструпа нет. На С программировал не много. На трудности жаловаться не приходиться поэтому сделал так как сделал. У меня тоже были много вопросов вроде ваших (например, почему функции должны возвращать unsigned long???), но мне дали ТЗ и все. Ну остальное мой косяк конечно же. Многое подзабыл. После Джавы кажется что я оказался в лесу окруженный деревьями с иголчатыми ветвями. Такие дела.

Comment: @Djasir ТЗ - это не догма, а руководство к действию.:) Многие положения из ТЗ могут быть пересмотрены по ходу реализации задания. Это в порядке вещей. Процесс разработки - это итерационный процесс.

Comment: @Djasir По поводу возвращаемого значения, то может быть в проекте есть уже заранее определенный список ошибок и соответствующие функцию, которые, например, выводят сообщение об ошибке в соответствии с кодом ошибки. В этом случае действительно код ошибки может задаваться как unsigned int. Но это надо как раз сверить с ТЗ: то ли действительно имеется продуманная система генерации и анализа ошибок, то ли это просто  взято, как говорится, с потолка.

Comment: В том то и вся загвоздка. Я не знаю что у них там. Поэтому просто тупо пишу по ТЗ. Чтобы было чем аргументировать если что)

Answer (score 3):

Ошибок... видимо не видимо:)

По поводу ругательства компилятора. Переменная pRandomBlock в первой функции - это двойной указатель. Стрелка (`->`) разыменовывает один раз и возвращает указатель. Логично, что это не структура, а указатель на эту структуру и поля там не будет. Можно сделать так

```
(*pRandomBlock)->ulRandomLen = GenerateRandomNumber(0, 128);
```

В следующей строке тоже самое.

Функция `FreeRandomBlock` скорее всего всегда будет возвращать `-1`. Почему? Все просто - free не меняет указатель. Я даже не знаю как там сделать красиво. Если туда придет невалидный указатель, то free упадет. Но  может и не сразу. И исключение вряд ли нормально получиться обработать. Я бы просто возвращал ноль и не переживал.

В функции `GenerateRandomNumber` есть одна невидимая проблема. Ее тип - `unsigned int`, а возвращает она почему то в некоторых случаях `-1`. Компилятор может ругаться, а может и сделать что то неочевидное. Нужно смотреть на описание структуры `RANDOM_BLOCK`.

Comment: @Djasir, IMHO правильней всего сделать `void FreeRandomBlock(...)` (поскольку сама `free()` тоже void).

Comment: В своем коде я бы сделал это все void (хотя я скорее все сделал по другому и мне подобная функция даже и не понадобилась), но у ТС похоже есть задание, по которому нужно сделать. А там описана сигнатура.

Comment: Дурацкое ТЗ всегда лучше оспорить (хотя, для этого нужна уверенность, что разбираешься в предмете не хуже оппонента (даже если он препод в институте)). (а по сигнатуре, в самом деле надо всегда возвращать 0).

Comment: Как показывает практика, в некоторых случаях лучше выполнить все строго по ТЗ. Тогда оттдуваться за плохое ТЗ будет тот, кто его написал. Конечно, нужно не забыть описать, что именно не нравиться и почему.

Comment: Кстати, теоретически некоторые ошибки с "ломаным" указателем можно отлавливать по `signal(SIGSEGV, ...)` / От всего это не спасет, да и накладно, но в принципе работает.

Answer (score 2):

В функцию *GenerateRandomBlock()* Вы передаете двойной указатель, а обращаетесь с этой переменной, как с обычным указателем. Обратиться к полям структуры в данном случае можно так :

```
(*pRandomBlock)->ulRandomLen = GenerateRandomNumber(0, 128);
```